# is there any function in sklearn that implements augmented frequency?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am not familiar with sklearn library. 
is there any function in sklearn that implements augmented frequency defined as following ?

[image]

where f(t,d) is the number associated with word t and document d in term-document matrix.

Comment: Ok, I think I have to implement by myself. thx !

Answer (score -1):

You can use the gensim api for augmented frequency. Use this link https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html for the installation and usage procedures.